# R commander, selecting statistic summary

Tags: r, r-commander

[![R commander table of statistics][1]][1]

Hello,

Is there any solution of how I choose all 'mean', 'median', 'SD', etc in statistics? Otherwise I will have to run all of them individually which is a pain.

In R commander, go to >statistics > summaries > table of statistics. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that's supposed to be an image, it didn't work.  Copied/pasted code would be better anyway.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it clearer.

Comment: I can't upload the image. I need 10 reputations

Comment: In R commander, go to >statistics > summaries > table of statistics.

Comment: The reason for the 10 rep ban is primarily to discourage screenshots. Please copy and paste the code text or error text as appropriate.